# Rails - Reload action with new value in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refresh, parameters

I have the following relation in my model:

**A user can have several consumers**

According to that, I call several actions from different controllers that depend on that **consumer_id** in the URL. So, I do stuff like:

```
/:consumer_id/products/all
/:consumer_id/locals/all?params...
```

I want to be able to given that I am in a particular view, let's say /3/products/all, be able to refresh, redirect or whatever is the best to /4/products/all, with a form that shows the different consumers attached to that user.

I know how to display the form, but I fail to see which action should I put given that I want to load the current controller, current action and the current params, except that I want to change the **params[:consumer_id]** and the **session[:consumer_id]** to the one chosen by the user in the form of the view.

What's the best or appropriate way of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the view you can access both the current controller using `controller_name` and the current action using `action_name`

Comment: What about if there are other params in the URL? So.. /:consumer_id/particular_action?param.. ?

Comment: Those should all be located in the params hash, which you can copy over to the new action

Comment: Upvoted. However, I am going to edit the question, because I am a little bit confused and I believe I haven't explained myself.

Answer (score 3):

This is a link to the same page with the same parameters and one additional parameter:

```
<%= link_to "Show more results", url_for(params.merge(:per => 100)) %>
```

If you want to modify a parameter rather than add a new one, you can modify the params hash just as you would modify any hash, and use url_for again.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. You want to choose consumer_id from your form, then use that consumer id inside the same page or for links to other pages?

If you want to use the consumer id for the current page, you need to use javascript or JQuery to update all attributes of the current page.

If you want to use that consumer id for links,

- you may also use JQuery to update all links on your page
- Or, you can submit the form to the server with new consumer_id.